# VBA script to read values from one worksheet and write to another (set range problem)

Tags: excel, vba, range, definition, type-mismatch

I'm struggling with a VBA subroutine and would appreciate some assistance. The script is intended to perform the following tasks:

1. Read values from column `LADUNGSNUMMER` in the worksheet `NVL` cell by cell.
2. Find each value in column `Transport` of the worksheet `DATA`.
3. Read the corresponding values from column `Faktura` (1:n relationship).
4. Concatenate these values into a string.
5. Write the concatenated string into column `EX-Fakturen` of the worksheet `NVL`.

Unfortunately, I'm encountering a `Types incompatible` error at the line:

```vb
Set transportColumn = .Range("Transport", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "Transport").End(xlUp)
```

However, I can retrieve the range successfully because `Debug.Print` returns the correct result. The issue seems to be with the definition. Could someone please take a look and provide some guidance?

```
Sub NVLFakturenLaden()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim loadNumberRange As Range
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim fakturaValue As String
    Dim counter As Long
    Dim transportColumn As Range
    Dim deliveryColumn As Range
    Dim deliveryCell As Range
    Dim deliveryValue As String
    Dim result As String
    
    ' Set the worksheet with the data
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("NVL")
    
    ' Define the range based on the named range "LADUNGSNUMMER"
    Set loadNumberRange = ws.Range("LADUNGSNUMMER")
    
    ' Initialize the counter
    counter = 0
    ' Loop through the cells in the named range "LADUNGSNUMMER"
    For Each cell In loadNumberRange
        ' Define the ranges for "Transport" and "Faktura" columns on the "DATA" worksheet
        With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DATA")
            If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Range("Transport")) > 0 Then
                ' Define the range
                Debug.Print Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Range("Transport"))
                Set transportColumn = .Range("Transport", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "Transport").End(xlUp))
            Else
                MsgBox "No data in the 'Transport' range.", vbExclamation
            End If
            If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Range("Faktura")) > 0 Then
                ' Define the range
                Set deliveryColumn = .Range("Faktura", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "Faktura").End(xlUp))
            Else
                MsgBox "No data in the 'Faktura' range.", vbExclamation
            End If
        End With
        
        ' Search for the value in the "Transport" column and concatenate corresponding "Faktura" values
        For Each deliveryCell In deliveryColumn
            If deliveryCell.value = cell.value Then
                deliveryValue = CStr(deliveryCell.value)
                
                ' Concatenate the "Faktura" value to the result
                If Len(result) > 0 Then
                    result = result & ", " & deliveryValue
                Else
                    result = deliveryValue
                End If
            End If
        Next deliveryCell
        
        ' Assign the result to the cell one column to the right of the current cell
        cell.Offset(0, 1).value = result
        
        ' Check if a Faktura was loaded
        If result <> "" Then
            counter = counter + 1
        End If
        
        ' Reset the result for the next iteration
        result = ""
    Next cell
    
    MsgBox "Factura loaded to " & counter & " transports.", vbInformation
End Sub
```

[image: Screenshots]

Debugging delivers

> Error 13

Comment: What is e.g. Transport? It should be a name referencing the (single) cell below the correct header cell. If it isn't, share which row on sheet data is the header row. The same for `Faktura`. Which exact range does the name `LADUNGSNUMMER` refer to? A wild guess would be that the 2nd `Transport` should be `.Range("Transport").Column` instead assuming that the range is the cell below the header. But then `If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Range("Transport")) = 1 Then` should be sufficient.

Comment: I've only now discovered the screenshot. Are these Excel tables? If so, that will make things much easier. What are their names?

Comment: Yes, there are two tables placed in two Worksheets. 
Worksheet "NVL": table name "Tabelle1", Cell Range "LADUNGSNUMMER". Worksheet "DATA": table name "MONITOR", Cell Ranges "Transport", "Faktura".
The idea is to find a value from the 'LADUNGSNUMMER' column in the 'Transport' column and return the appropriate values from the 'Faktura' column concatenated into one string. It looks like a LookUp formula with multiple values to be returned, concatenated into one string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### A Delimited VBA Lookup in Excel (Structured) Tables

- If you have MS365, Office 2021, and I'm not sure about Office 2019, you could use the following formula in the first cell of column `EX_Fakturen` (clear the column first):

  ```
  =TEXTJOIN(", ",,FILTER(Monitor[Faktura],Monitor[Transport]=[@LADUNGSNUMMER],""))
  ```

[image]

```vb
Sub LookupFakturas()

    Const SRC_SHEET_NAME As String = "Data"
    Const SRC_TABLE_INDEX As Long = 1
    Const SRC_LOOKUP_COLUMN_TITLE As String = "Transport"
    Const SRC_RETURN_COLUMN_TITLE As String = "Faktura"
    Const DST_SHEET_NAME As String = "NVL"
    Const DST_TABLE_INDEX As Long = 1
    Const DST_LOOKUP_COLUMN_TITLE As String = "LADUNGSNUMMER"
    Const DST_RETURN_COLUMN_TITLE As String = "EX_Fakturen"
    Const DELIMITER As String = ", "
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    Dim slData As Variant, srData As Variant
    
    With wb.Sheets(SRC_SHEET_NAME).ListObjects(SRC_TABLE_INDEX)
        slData = .ListColumns(SRC_LOOKUP_COLUMN_TITLE).DataBodyRange.Value
        srData = .ListColumns(SRC_RETURN_COLUMN_TITLE).DataBodyRange.Value
    End With
    
    Dim drrg As Range, dlData As Variant
    
    With wb.Sheets(DST_SHEET_NAME).ListObjects(DST_TABLE_INDEX)
        dlData = .ListColumns(DST_LOOKUP_COLUMN_TITLE).DataBodyRange.Value
        Set drrg = .ListColumns(DST_RETURN_COLUMN_TITLE).DataBodyRange
    End With
    
    Dim dict As Object: Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Dim drCount As Long: drCount = UBound(dlData, 1)
    
    Dim r As Long
    For r = 1 To drCount
        dict(CStr(dlData(r, 1))) = r
    Next r
    Erase dlData
    
    Dim drData() As String: ReDim drData(1 To drCount, 1 To 1)
    
    Dim sStr As String, sr As Long, dr As Long
    
    For sr = 1 To UBound(slData, 1)
        sStr = CStr(slData(sr, 1))
        If dict.Exists(sStr) Then
            dr = dict(sStr)
            If drData(dr, 1) = vbNullString Then
                drData(dr, 1) = srData(sr, 1)
            Else
                drData(dr, 1) = drData(dr, 1) & DELIMITER & srData(sr, 1)
            End If
        End If
    Next sr
    
    drrg.Value = drData
    
    MsgBox "Fakturas looked up.", vbInformation
    
End Sub
```

Comment: It works exactly as expected. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Caution, there was a mistake. I accidentally used `SRC_TABLE_INDEX` instead of `DST_TABLE_INDEX` for the destination sheet. Make sure to fix it if you haven't already. It is barely detectable since I used the first table for both sheets but if you one day decide to use the table names instead, there would be an error.